# ActivatedRoute parameter is empty

Tags: angular, url, routes

A lot of people had this problem, but none of the solutions worked for me.

**My router module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'screen/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'index.jsp', redirectTo: 'screen/home' },
    { path: 'screen/home', component:HomeComponent },
    { path: 'screen/logs', component:LogsComponent },
    { path: 'screen/logs/job-logs', component:JobLogsComponent},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**The component that reroutes**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './logs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./logs.component.scss'],
})
export class LogsComponent {    
constructor(
        private route:Router,
    ){
    }
    getJobLogs(jobId:String){
        this.route.navigate(['/screen/logs/job-logs'],{queryParams: {jobId}});
    }
}
```

**The component where I'm trying to retrieve the parameter**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './job-logs.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./job-logs.component.scss'],
})
export class JobLogsComponent{
    jobId: String;
    constructor(
        private route:ActivatedRoute,
    ){

        console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("jobId"));
        this.jobId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('jobId');
        this.jobId = this.route.params['jobId'];
        this.route.params.subscribe(params=>
            this.jobId=params['jobId']
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried to get the parameters in the onInit method too.

The url will be something like
`http://localhost:4200/screen/logs/job-logs?jobId=9oEZbtlZRCip86iFtQj6EQ`

I've tried inputting the parameter manually in the URL to something simpler like 23, but no success.

**The routing module of the jobs-logs**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { JobLogsComponent } from './job-logs.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: JobLogsComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: JobLogsComponent }
        ])
    ],
})
export class JobLogsRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed this path :

```
{ path: 'screen/logs/job-logs/:id', component:JobLogsComponent},
```

Comment: I tried that before, but then I have an error saying the url "screen/logs/job-logs/" has no routing.
But if I just add that line, nothing changes.
I also debugged in the browser and the component is called.

Comment: Did you create a routing-module for this component ?

Comment: I did, I edited it in at the end

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out why the ActivatedRoute Class doesn't work properly.

But I noticed the member url from the Router Class was working.

So I figured out a workaround with the Router class.

```
this.jobId = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams['jobId'];
```